# Drupal how to make a popup?

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, popup, head

I am new to Drupal, I just installed Drupal locally for the first time.
I want to make a pop up when the page is loaded that will lead to an article that I created.

I saw a way to do it using this code I found online :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>ColorBox demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, there!</h1>
    <h2>This is some content</h2>
    <p>The popup will open in five seconds</p>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js">    </script>
    <script>
      function openColorBox(){
        $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: "http://www.sitepoint.com"});
      }

      setTimeout(openColorBox, 5000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Although this code seems to be working when I test it on it's own , I don't know how to edit the head and body section of my Drupal page. Is there any way to achieve that or another way to make the popup?

Answer (score 0):

First you should install the colorbox module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox

Then in your template.php you can add inline script in this way:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () {function openColorBox(){
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: "http://www.sitepoint.com"});
  }setTimeout(openColorBox, 5000); });', 'inline');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I want the popup for a project, so I can't use modules. I want to use as much coding as I can, so calling the colorbox using coding is preferable. The only thing I want to manage now is calling the css file correctly, and having the popup at the first page only. And since I am not that good at php, that will be a problem